# Error while running Uninstall-SitecoreConfiguration SIF method

Tags: sitecore-install-framework, installation, powershell

I'm trying to use **SIF 2.0 to uninstall** a no longer used Sitecore 9.1 instance.

This method used to work perfectly with previous versions and I know that for sure since I'm quite a hard user.

I don't know exactly if that's something with SIF 2.0 or something with my given instance. It's a **vanilla Sitecore 9.1 + SPE 5.0 + SXA 1.8**.

```
[------------------------------------------------------------------------- SitecoreXP0_RemoveHostHeader : HostHeader ------------------------------------
[SitecoreXP0_RemoveHostHeader]:[Backup] Created - C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.backup
Removing host entry for 127.0.0.1 with hostname 'Sitecore91.SXA.sc'...
Uninstall-SitecoreConfiguration : Stream was not readable.
At C:\Sitecore\Install Packages\9.1\XP0\XP0-SingleDeveloper.ps1:77 char:1
+ Uninstall-SitecoreConfiguration @singleDeveloperParams *>&1 | Tee-Obj ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:00:07
Set-Content : Stream was not readable.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.0.0\Public\Tasks\Invoke-HostHeaderTask.ps1:57 char:4
+             Set-Content -Path $hostsFile -Value $updatedHostsContent  ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts:String) [Set-Content], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetContentWriterArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand
```

Comment: Did your host file get wiped out? This has happened to me and the SIF-less creator (Rob) a few times.

Comment: Right on point @MichaelWest. Hopefully enough it looks like SIF made a `host.backup` file before pranking me, so I'm back on the game. But did you find the cause of this weird behavior?

Comment: I believe there is a bug in the SIF module. Rob told me about it on slack. Reach out to him if you need some more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in SIF/ Set-content. This is now fixed in version 2.1, run `Update-Module -Name SitecoreInstallFramework` .

It's caused by another application, usually Chrome or VS code taking control of the hosts file while it's being written to.

For now, make sure that you don't have Chrome or similar running when you do the uninstall. Then it should be OK.

C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.backup is a backup of the file you can use that to restore the hosts file.

Comment: Thanks especially for the C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.backup note!